# trigger unload leads to error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an Onlineshop what uses a Plugin that's called **thickbox**

Now thickbox seems to be a lil old but it was used in the shop and i don't really want to change a lot in there. actually its running.

Now if a Customer clicks on the Image to see it zoomed, it opens some like a lightbox.

```
<div id="TB_overlay" class="TB_overlayBG"></div>
<div id="TB_window" style="margin-left: -335px; width: 670px; margin-top: -350px; display: block;">
    <a href="" id="TB_ImageOff" title="Close">
        <img id="TB_Image" src="images/product_images/popup_images/TJ3000-1.jpg" width="640" height="640">
    </a>
    <div id="TB_caption">FooBar<div id="TB_secondLine">Image 1 / 1</div>
</div>
<div id="TB_closeWindow">
    <a href="#" id="TB_closeWindowButton" title="Close">X</a>
</div>
```

if he clicks it again, than thickbox calls a function `tb_remove` what actually makes sense!

```
function tb_remove() {

    $("#TB_imageOff").unbind("click");
    $("#TB_closeWindowButton").unbind("click");
    $("#TB_window").fadeOut("fast",function(){$('#TB_window,#TB_overlay,#TB_HideSelect').trigger('unload').unbind().remove();});
    $("#TB_load").remove();
    if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight == "undefined") {//if IE 6
        $("body","html").css({height: "auto", width: "auto"});
        $("html").css("overflow","");
    }
    document.onkeydown = "";
    document.onkeyup = "";
    return false;
}
```

but the overlay won't close!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null      //jquery-ui.js:84
```

if i remove `.trigger('unload')` from

```
$('#TB_window,#TB_overlay,#TB_HideSelect').trigger('unload').unbind().remove();
```

than it seems to work.

what does `trigger('unload')` do in this case?

and is it really neede ?

my thought were, if a item is removed, it doesn't matters anyway because its actually deleted.

or am i wrong ?!?!?

**EDIT**

that's the only unload handler i find.. and i guess i will never end up there because the imagename is always given.

```
if(urlType == '.jpg' || urlType == '.jpeg' )
{
    //code to show images
    //source that actually shows the lightbox
}
else
{
    //code to show html
    //some source
    $("#TB_window").unload(function () {
        $('#' + params['inlineId']).append( $("#TB_ajaxContent").children() ); // move elements back when you're finished
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what does `trigger('unload')` do in this case?

[`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) calls any jQuery-registered handlers for the `unload` event on those elements, and then tries to trigger the native `unload` event on those elements to fire any native (non-jQuery) handlers.

Unless you (or that plug-in) have code somewhere hooking `unload` on those elements, you could remove it. But based on that causing a problem, my guess is that the plug-in hooks that event for some reason, and that that's where things are failing...